# Variables from config file in bash:Syntax error :operand expected (error token is "<")

Tags: bash, ubuntu, for-loop, configuration-files

So I have this config file in which the set the value such as

```
config.sh

nFiles=2

myScript.sh

for ((i=0;i<$nFiles;i++));
do
     mv -v $FILE_GEN_SOURCE/${FILES[i]} $FILE_DEST;
done
```

But this gives me this

```
error: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
```

I tried removing the $, then the default value of nFiles becomes 0. So any ideas on what is wrong here and what can be done to correct this?

Comment: I tried `nFiles=10;for ((i=0;i < $nFiles;i++));do echo "$nFiles";done` and works for me

Comment: Is this "config.sh" or is it calling "config.sh"? I think you may have a loop of files calling and sourcing each other.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson config.sh just has the value nFiles=2 being assigned to it. myScript.sh sources the config.sh and then the for loop. But for some reason, the nFiles value is not getting stored or it is not being recognized

Comment: So in your question, the lines with filenames are not part of any script - they're part of the question to serve to delineate the two separate scripts? If that's the case, then myScript.sh never sources config.sh and *there's your problem*. See kev's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need `source config.sh` at the beginning of `myScript.sh`.

`myScript.sh` cannot access `nFiles` from `config.sh`.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
# myScript.sh

source config.sh

for ((i=0;i<$nFiles;i++));
do
     mv -v $FILE_GEN_SOURCE/${FILES[i]} $FILE_DEST;
done
```

Comment: Have you put `source config.sh` inside your `myScript.sh`?

Comment: @user1357576: No, you haven't. Not based on what you're showing in the question.